# What has gone wrong with this sorting code using Linked Lists?

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to say that I just started learning C++ and I'm having a fairly good grip on just insertion, deletion, reversing, finding the element and element in a position. I've tried to sort using Bubble Sort(?) and the program is crashing. Please help me.

```
struct node
{
int data;
struct node* link;
};
typedef struct node* NODE;

NODE rearr(NODE root)
{
NODE temp=root;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    NODE curr=temp;
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        if(curr->data>(curr->link)->data)
    {
        int temp1=curr->data;
        curr->data=(curr->link)->data;
        (curr->link)->data=temp1;
    }
    curr=curr->link;
    }
    temp=temp->link;
}return root;
}
```

There are insert and delete functions too, but I haven't copied here. If you want, I'll post the whole program.

Comment: At least you should initialize `struct node* link;` properly, add a constructor `node() : data(0), link(NULL) {}`

Answer (score 0):

You never test to see if `curr->link` is null or not. Which causes a fault when you check its `data` memeber.

```
if(curr->link != NULL && curr->data>(curr->link)->data)
```